# Minesweeper: How to Dynamic a lot of graphics with high-speed?

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, dynamic, gui-construction, game

Recently I've implemented Minesweeper in *Mathematica*.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
path = "https://i.stack.imgur.com//" <> # &;
filenames1 = {"P22Go.jpg", "Zh27M.jpg", "vKZZr.jpg", "2CYDF.png"};
{TL, BR, clock, mine} = Import /@ path /@ filenames1;
{topleft, bottomright} = ImageData /@ {TL, BR};
filenames2 = {"VngIV.jpg", "WeIqo.jpg", "fvub6.jpg", "rb5P7.jpg", 
   "fl5W2.jpg", "NowyY.jpg", "5Pp3F.jpg", "9pNCj.jpg", "vMIXr.jpg"};
numberpictures[n_] := 
  numberpictures[n] = Import[path@filenames2[[n + 1]]];

backgroundcolor = RGBColor[0.698, 0.757, 0.831];
spacecolor = RGBColor[0.839, 0.890, 0.953];
numbercolor = 
  RGBColor @@@ {{0.247, 0.314, 0.737}, {0.122, 0.408, 0.004}, {0.682, 0.008, 0.020},   
       {0.027, 0.004, 0.502}, {0.49, 0, 0}, {0, 0.49, 0.495}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};

back[i_, j_] := back[i, j] = 
   With[{ii = Rescale[i, {1, 16}], jj = Rescale[j, {1, 30}]}, 
    Image[(1 - (ii + jj)/2) topleft + (ii + jj)/2 bottomright]];
block[{i_, j_, type1_, type2_}] := block[i, j, type1, type2] = 
   Switch[type1,
    0, back[i, j],
    1, Switch[type2,
     0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8, numberpictures[type2],
     9, ImageCompose[back[i, j], mine]
     ]
    ];

ini := Module[{mat1, mat2, modify},
   modify[mat_, {i_, j_}] := 
    If[mat[[i, j]] != 9, 
     ReplacePart[mat, {i, j} -> 
       Count[mat[[Max[1, i - 1] ;; Min[16, i + 1], 
         Max[1, j - 1] ;; Min[30, j + 1]]], 9, 2]], mat];
   mat1 = Table[{i, j, 0}, {i, 16}, {j, 30}];
   mat2 = Partition[RandomSample[
      Flatten@{9 & /@ Range[99], 0 & /@ Range[16*30 - 99]}], 30];
   mat2 = Map[List, Fold[modify[#1, #2] &, mat2, 
      Flatten[Array[{#1, #2} &, {16, 30}], 1]], {2}];
   Join[mat1, mat2, 3]];
CreateDialog[
 DynamicModule[{board = ini}, 
  Dynamic@Column@{Spacer[30], 
     GraphicsGrid[Map[block, board, {2}], ImageSize -> 1200, 
      Spacings -> {0, 0}, Frame -> All, 
      FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]], 
     Row[{Spacer[60], clock, Spacer[700], mine, Spacer[30]}]}, 
  Initialization :> (
    getpos[] := 
     With[{pos = MousePosition["Graphics"]}, 
      If[pos === None, 
       None, {-1, 1}*Quotient[Reverse@pos, 360] + {0, 1}]];
    click[board_, "Left"] := 
     With[{coor = getpos[]}, 
      If[coor === None, board, 
       ReplacePart[board, Flatten[{coor, 3}] -> 1]]]; 
    SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
     NotebookEventActions -> {{"MouseUp", 
         1} :> (board = click[board, "Left"]), {"MouseUp", 
         2} :> {"Right ", Print@getpos[]}}])], 
 Background -> backgroundcolor, WindowTitle -> "Minesweeper By apple",
  WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}]
```

There are `16*30 = 480` blocks in the final interface. If I write that `Dynamic[...(*480 blocks*)]`, when I click any cell, it will redraw all the interface (480 blocks or more) and will respond after 2 seconds. I don't know how to just dynamic small part of the final interface. How to make it response with high-speed?

**Update 1**

Since it is not a good idea to put `Dynamic` over the whole application, I rewrote my code in ugly way:

```
DynamicModule[{board = ini}, 
 GraphicsGrid[
   {{Dynamic@block@var[1, 1], Dynamic@block@var[1, 2], Dynamic@block@var[1, 3],and so on}, 
    {Dynamic@block@var[2, 1], Dynamic@block@var[2, 2], Dynamic@block@var[2, 3],and so on},
     and so on}}}], 
 Initialization :> (
   getpos[] := some code;
   click["Left"] := somecode; 
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> somecode])]
```

`var[1, 1]` maybe equal to `{1,1,0,3}`, `{1,1}` means this block is in row 1, column 1, 0 means this block was not clicked yet, 3 means there are 3 mines around this block.

Now click will be：

```
click["Left"]:= With[{coor=getpos[]},board[Sequence@@coor][[3]]=1]
```

But this is not allowed.

```
Block[{x}, x[1] = {0, 0, 0}; x[1][[2]] = 11; x[1]]
```

> Set::setps: "x[1] in the part assignment is not a symbol."

We only can do something like this:

```
Block[{x1}, x1 = {0, 0, 0}; x1[[2]] = 11; x1]
```

> {0, 11, 0}

Then I rewrote my code again..

```
vars = Table[ToExpression["boardR" <> ToString[i] <> "C" <> ToString[j]], {i, 16}, {j, 30}];
Evaluate@vars = ini;

DynamicModule[{}, 
 GraphicsGrid[
   {{Dynamic@block@boardR1C1, Dynamic@block@boardR1C2, Dynamic@block@boardR1C3,and so on}, 
    {Dynamic@block@boardR2C1, Dynamic@block@boardR2C2, Dynamic@block@boardR2C3,and so on},
     and so on}}}], 
 Initialization :> (
   getpos[] := some code;
   click["Left"] := somecode; 
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], NotebookEventActions -> somecode])]
```

now click will be more complex:

```
click["Left"]:=With[{coor=getpos[]},Set[(ToExpression[
"boardR" <> ToString[coor[[1]]] <> "C" <> ToString[coor[[2]]]])[[3]], 1]]
```

But this will also cause other problems, since:

```
a=3;
Set[ToExpression["a"],2]
```

> Set::write: Tag ToExpression in ToExpression[a] is Protected.

So currently all the efforts I did have failed.

**Update 2**

1:

```
x[1] = {1, 2, 3};
Module[{temp},
 temp = x[1];
 temp[[2]] = 4;
 x[1] = temp;
 ]
x[1]
```

> {1, 4, 3}

2:

```
a=3;
ToExpression["a"<>"=2"]
a
```

> 2

Now maybe I can finish my code.

**Update 3**

This game is not finished (now 2014.11.24). There are a lot of features not included.

```
NotebookPut@
 ImportString[
  Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Drop[#, -Last@#] &@
   Flatten@ImageData[
     Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wGyI.png"], "Byte"], 
  "NB"]
```

Comment: I don't think Mathematica is really meant for this kind of applications...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries But still, I don't see why this can't be achievable in Mathematica. The Dynamic paradigm is not the fastest, and its implementation also doesn't seem to be very speed optimized (but I don't know if this last is true or not). Nevertheless, I think I've done worse than what this minesweeper is asking for, and still I was pretty happy with the achievements. This is definitely a thing that I'll give a try, as soon as I have some time available.

Comment: @P.Fonseca Probably achievable yes, but to what end? As Sjoerd points out Mathematica is not really intended for this kind of application.  I could (in principle) bang in a nail with a spanner but a hammer is a better tool for that job.  You could implement the UI in java and put the game logic/state in Mathematica and tie it together with JLink?

Comment: Don't have more time, but meanwhile: `(# = 3) &@ToExpression["a", InputForm, Unevaluated]`

Comment: Or `ToExpression["a=" <> ToString[3]]`

Comment: It works!@Kuba @Simon Woods

Comment: mildly related http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24179/315

Comment: Use another language for games :)

Comment: "People who say it cannot be done should not interrupt those who are doing it."  - George Bernard Shaw. ;)

Comment: @pickett that's a nice one :) I think that this is a very interesting interface that has applications well beyond this game, and so, I'm glad the question was asked, and even more that we can profit from the solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue with such multicontroller dynamic interfaces is that one usually wants to store the state of all controllers in one variable for convenience (e.g. store status of position `{i, j}` as `state[{i, j}] := "flagged"` or `state = <|{1, 1} -> 2, {1, 2} -> "flagged", ...|>`). On one hand, this makes assignments easy during updating, but on the other hand, any change to `state` triggers an interface update of all cells as they all track the single variable `state`. And in this case, it involves the visual updating of 480 cells. Using `Graphic`-s or `Image`-s makes updating even slower.

Unfortunately, **[there is no mechanism (yet) to dynamically track parts of expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64312/5478)** without updating the whole expression (parts of a symbol, without updating the whole symbol), something like:

```
(* hypothetic construct, won't work *)
Dynamic[display[state[{1, 2}]], TrackedSymbols :> {state[{1, 2}]}
```

One possible solution is to introduce 480 independent symbols as variables, one for each cell, but this requires metaprogramming methods to generate and set the symbols.

Here is a proof-of-principle for this approach that uses the excellent method of programmatic symbol assignment from [Kuba & John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83129/89). I've replaced the imported graphics with domestic frame-and-style ones, as those are much faster printed. One can make code even faster by fine-tuning recursive `reveal` to only visit every relevant cell once. Now it is quite redundant, but the fact is that this extra traversal is marginal compared to the time needed for visual updating of the interface. A large part of the code is to detect simultaneous L-R clicks.

Note: `m1` and `m2` is invisibly displayed so that they are correctly tracked.

[image]

```
ClearAll[toString, set, reveal, neighbors, reset, end, lr];

{m, n, k} = {9, 9, 10}; (* Beginner *)
{m, n, k} = {16, 16, 40};(* Intermediate *)
{m, n, k} = {16, 30, 99};(* Expert *)
seed = 1;

pos = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, m}, {j, n}], 1];
st = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "N", "F"};
bg = {"N" | "F" -> GrayLevel@.7, _ -> GrayLevel@.9};
fg = {
   1 -> RGBColor[0.247, 0.314, 0.737], 
   2 -> RGBColor[0.122, 0.408, 0.004], 
   3 -> RGBColor[0.682, 0.008, 0.02], 
   4 -> RGBColor[0.027, 0.004, 0.502],
   5 -> RGBColor[0.49, 0, 0], 
   6 -> RGBColor[0, 0.49, 0.495], 
   "F" -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], _ -> GrayLevel[0]};
lbl = {9 -> "\[MathematicaIcon]", 0 -> "", "F" -> "\[SpadeSuit]", x_Integer :> x, _ -> ""};
pics = AssociationMap[
   Framed[Style[# /. lbl, Bold, # /. fg], Background -> (# /. bg), 
     ImageSize -> {20, 20}, Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}, 
     FrameMargins -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, FrameStyle -> None] &, st];

(* Convert position to symbol name *)
toString[{i_, j_}] := StringJoin["s", ToString@i, "x", ToString@j];
(* Assign `val` to symbol of name `str` *)
set[str_, val_] := ToExpression@MakeBoxes[RawBoxes@str = val];
(* Reveal cell at position `p` and update symbol `s` (string) *)
reveal[p_, s_] := Module[{c}, If[ToExpression@s === "N", c = counts@p; 
    If[c == 9, end@False, set[s, c];
     If[c == 0, reveal[#, toString@#] & /@ neighbors@p]]]];
(* Return 3x3 submatrix centered at position `{i, j}` *)
neighbors[{i_, j_}] := Flatten[Outer[List, Range[Max[1, i - 1], Min[m, i + 1]], 
    Range[Max[1, j - 1], Min[n, j + 1]]], 1];
(* Reset game *)
reset[s_: Automatic] := Module[{mines},
   {msg, f, m1, m2} = {"", 0, 0, 0};
   seed = If[s === Automatic, RandomInteger@999999, s];
   SeedRandom@seed;
   mines = AssociationThread[pos -> RandomSample@PadRight[Table[1, {k}], m n]];
   counts = AssociationMap[If[mines@# > 0, 9, Total@Lookup[mines, neighbors@#]] &, pos];
   str = toString /@ pos; (* generate a symbol name for each cell *)
   ClearAll /@ str; (* clear these symbols in case they exist *)
   set[#, "N"] & /@ str; (* set all symbols to "N" (not clicked) *)
   ];
(* Terminate game *)
end[win_] := (MapThread[set[#1, counts@#2] &, {str, pos}]; 
   msg = Style[If[win, "\[HappySmiley]", "\[SadSmiley]"], 16]);
(* Event for simultaneous L-R click *)
lr[p_, s_] := (If[ToExpression@s =!= "N" && ToExpression@s =!= "F", 
    m1 = m2 = 0; Module[{c = counts@p, nb = neighbors@p, v},
     v = ToExpression@*toString /@ nb;
     If[c === 0 || Count[v, "F"] === c, 
      reveal[#, toString@#] & /@ Pick[nb, v, "N"]]]]);

reset@seed;
Deploy@Grid[{
   {Button["New", reset[]], Button["Reset", reset@seed], 
    InputField[Dynamic[seed, (seed = #; reset@#) &], Number, 
     FieldSize -> 5]},
   {Dynamic@(k - f), Dynamic@msg, Invisible@Dynamic@{m1, m2}},
   {Deploy@Grid[Partition[MapThread[
        EventHandler[Dynamic@pics@ToExpression@#2, {
           {"MouseClicked", 1} :> (m1 = SessionTime[]; 
             If[0 < m1 - m2 < .2, lr[#1, #2], reveal[#1, #2]]; 
             If[(Count[ToExpression /@ str, "N"] + f) === k, 
              end@True]),
           {"MouseClicked", 2} :> (m2 = SessionTime[]; 
             If[0 < m2 - m1 < .2, lr[#1, #2];,
              Switch[ToExpression@#2, "N", f++; set[#2, "F"], "F", f--;
                set[#2, "N"], _, Null]])
           }] &, {pos, str}], n], Spacings -> {.1, .1}, 
      Background -> Black], SpanFromLeft}
   }, Spacings -> {.1, .1}, Alignment -> Left]
```

Comment: Finally, +1 :) Thanks for not abandoning us :)

Comment: For future readers, here are few topic related to the core problem: [174792](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174792/5478), [128344](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128344/5478), [64312](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64312/5478)

Comment: I just edited tags to add **performance-tuning,** and I deleted **symbols**.  Only after did I realize you had just added the latter.  If you feel strongly that it should be there could you explain why?  Oh, and +1 of course! :-)

Comment: @Kuba thank you for the warm welcome :) I never intended to abandon SE, but I had other obligations (work, familiy, and a baby) and I gained a considerable amount of extra time giving up certain hobbies. You all know how a simple checking of Mathematica.SE could lead to a week long research and optimization and bug-hunting-fest. I got out before my superiors (boss, wife, baby, you name it) recognized a performance drop in my output.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You are right, `[symbols]` is not really fitting here. I've only included it because of the algorithmic generation of unique symbols, but that is not the main point here, and there are better posts for that. I'm fine with your edit, thank you.