# Programming the fiver game

Tags: programming, dynamic, gui-construction, game

Obviously, even if I ask a lot of question I am, obviously, still a dummy!!!!

I want to program the fiver game.  It's a very simple game played solitary on a $5 \times 5$ the rule is elementary : if you click with the mouse on a cell it changes color along with its von-Neuman neighbours --- north, south, east and west. The solution is far from trivial and can be obtain by integer programming. You win if you manage to change all the cells to the alternative color.

So according to my analysis

**Initialization**

$\forall (i,j) \in \{1, 5\}^2$ color c[i,j] = LightBlue

This I can do

```
cell[i_, j_] := Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Blue]], 
     Scale[Rectangle[{i, j}], .5]}]
GraphicsGrid[Table[cell[i, j], {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}], 
     Background -> LightYellow, Spacings -> Scaled[-.03]]
```

[image]

Here I have a two problems secondary problems :

1) The Spacings seems to have nearly no effects --- I want the minimum spacing

2) If I click with the mouse on a square, I can displace it which, in this case, must be forbiden.

Then follows the analysis of the cases ---~I hope not to have make a mistake.

A) If I click on $cell[i,j]$ for ${i,j} \in \{2, 3, 4\}^2$ then
 the cells  $cell[i-1, j]$, $cell[i, j]$, $cell[i+1, j]$, $cell[i, j+1]$ and $cell[i, j-1]$ must have a change in color --- say from LightBlue to LightRed or from LightRed to LightBlue.

B) If I click on $cell[i,j]$ for $\{i,j\} \in \{1\}\times\{2,3,4\}$  then cells
$cell[1, j-1]$, $cell[1, j]$, $cell[1, j+1]$ and $cell[2, j]$ must have a change in color.

C) If I click on $cell[i,j]$ for $\{i,j\} \in \{5\}\times\{2,3,4\}$  then cells
$cell[5, j-1]$, $cell[5, j]$, $cell[5, j+1]$ and $cell[4, j]$ must have a change in color.

D) If I click on $cell[i,j]$ for $\{i,j\} \in \{2,3,4\}\times \{1\}$  then cells
$cell[i-1, 1]$, $cell[i, 1]$, $cell[i+1, 1]$ and $cell[i, 2]$ must have a change in color.

E) If I click on $cell[i,j]$ for $\{i,j\} \in \{2,3,4\}\times \{5\}$  then cells
$cell[i-1, 5]$, $cell[i, 5]$, $cell[i+1, 5]$ and $cell[i, 4]$ must have a change in color.

F) If I click on $cell[1,1]$ then $cell[1,1]$, $cell[2,1]$ and $cell[1,2]$ must have a change in color.

G) If I click on $cell[1,5]$ then $cell[1,5]$, $cell[1,4]$ and $cell[2,5]$ must have a change in color.

H) If I click on $cell[5,5]$ then $cell[5,5]$, $cell[4,5]$ and $cell[5,4]$ must have a change in color.

I) If I click on $cell[5,1]$ then $cell[5,1]$, $cell[4,1]$ and $cell[5,2]$ must have a change in color.

If I understand correctly the Mma commands, I need EventHandler and DynamicModule. Unfortunatelly, I have made some trials which gives nothing because, I think, I do not know how to program the fact that any click inside a square must trigger the change.

I do not ask  the work be done for me completelly but I need some help. Thanks

Comment: Spacings have effect, but `Graphics` in each cell introduces `ImageMargins`, `PlotRangePadding` etc etc. So a better way is to just have one `Graphics` and a grid of rectangles inside.

Comment: Very Nice. Be reassured it's not home work. I am a university professor in economics. I always have been dependent of other to program and now I have decided to try to do it by myself. For some elements it's esy to do it for other less. I take note and try to present to my collegues the advantage to use mathematica even over R and other free softwares. This I cannot do with yourcollective  help. So I will never thank you enough. For instance, I will never had though to a flip function . As it is finally your work dear Kuba, it will be nice to wrap it in a demonstration project.

Comment: For large "boards" the method I used will get very slow; for a faster approach in such cases see [(66133)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66133/121).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In this case I don't know how to post something helpful without providing full code so I'll just do that and hope this wasn't homework.  My emphasis is on clarity (hopefully) rather than brevity or peak efficiency.

```
flip = # /. {LightRed -> LightBlue, LightBlue -> LightRed} &;

flipNeighbors[i_, j_] :=
 (color[##] = flip @ color[##];) & @@@ 
   {{i, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i - 1, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i, j - 1}}

ClearAll[color]
color[_, _] = LightBlue;

Grid[
  Array[
    Button[
      Spacer[{50, 50}]
      , flipNeighbors[##]
      , Background -> Dynamic @ color[##]
    ] &
    , {5, 5}
  ]
  , Spacings -> {-0.03, -0.01}
]
```

[image]

#### Notes

- Negative [`Spacings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacings.html) values are used to snug up the buttons.
- `ClearAll[color]; color[_, _] = LightBlue;` should be evaluated to reset the board.
- [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html) should be used, with localization for `flip`, `flipNeighbors`, and `color`, if you want the game to appear correctly when you first open a Notebook containing it.
- `Appearance -> None` may be used as a Option for [`Button`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html) if you do not like the "3D" border.
- I made the value of the Button `Background` Dynamic, rather than the entire `Grid`, for improved performance.

---

### The full monty

This is a fun little game so I wrote code for my own reuse.  I might as well share it. :-)

The output may be copied and used independently, with controls to reset the board and change the colors when your eyes get tired.

```
DynamicModule[{flip, v, c, square, gui},
 flip[i_, j_] :=
  (v[##] *= -1;) & @@@
   {{i, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i - 1, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i, j - 1}};

 _v = 1;
 {c[1], c[-1], c[0]} = {LightBlue, LightRed, Gray};

 square =
  Button[
    Spacer[{51, 51}], flip @ ##
    , Background -> Dynamic @ c @ v @ ##
    , Appearance -> None
  ] &;

 gui =
  Labeled[ #
    , {Button["Reset", ClearAll[v]; _v = 1],
        ColorSetter@*Dynamic@*c /@ {1, -1, 0} // Column}
    , {Bottom, Right}
  ] &;

 Grid[
     Array[square, {5, 5}]
     , Frame -> c[0]
     , Background -> c[0]
     , Spacings -> {{5, {1}, 5}, {5, {1}, 5}}/10
 ] // gui // Deploy
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing for a variety of reasons: On the one hand, it's just amazing. On the other it's basically a coding tutorial. And finally, it's your only answer that I am aware of that you don't use infix `~#~` (+1 wholeheartedly)

Comment: @gpap I am glad you like it. :-)  Incidentally I don't think I really use infix that extensively, either in my answers here or in my own coding, I just use it where it is easier for *me* to read, which usually means where there would otherwise be a [[[stack[of[brackets]]]]] which I simply hate.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I am fascinated by how elegant the code is. I am trying o understand the code. Could you please explain how    `ColorSetter@*Dynamic@*c`  this code works especially `@*`

Comment: Useful code, three cheers

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I too am having difficulty picking apart this spectacular piece of coding! As I understand it, `_v = 1; v@# *= -1` evaluates alternately to $\pm \ 1$, but I get lost somewhere after it is applied to all elements of `i` and `j` inside flip, (without `Button`, it seems to evaluate to `Null Null Null Null Null`).

Comment: *(continued)*...  I would like to alter the start-state of the evaluation to look something like your [first image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F4tX9.png), where ramdom cells are shaded pink, as opposed to all blue. I tried applying different `v` values to the array, but wasn't succesful. Should I ask a separate stand-alone question?

Comment: @vikramreddy `@*` is shorthand for [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) that was added in version 10.  `ColorSetter@*Dynamic@*c`behaves typically the same as `(ColorSetter@Dynamic@c@# &)` but is a little cleaner to write.

Comment: @martin `_v = 1` is a short way to make any use of `v[arg1, . . .]` that is not otherwise defined evaluate to `1`.  This lets me do e.g. `v[3, 5] *= -1` without having to first set an explicit value for `v[3, 5]`.  The output of `flip` (a bunch of `Null` as noted) is irrelivant; I only want to change the `DownValues` of `v`, which are later used in `Background -> Dynamic @ c @ v @ ##` to define the colors of the squares.  If you want to flip the color of random squares you can set `v[i, j] = -1` for random values of `i` and `j` that are within the grid, but it may make the board unsolvable.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard got it - thanks :)

Comment: @martin Glad I could help.  Don't hesitate to ask if you have more questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I got it . Thanks. I tried to look up `@*` in the documentation but the documentation doesn't say anything. Then when i searched for `composition` I found it.

Comment: @vikram The search sometimes fails like that.  Next time you might start with [(18393)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/121)

Comment: Dear Mister Wizard, as i am not the autor of your code --- a nice totaulogy --- I wonder if you can put a cdf in the Wolfram repository.

Comment: @cyrille.piatecki I am not really interested in doing that.  If however you wish to, and you follow the existing (Stack Exchange) license requirement of attribution, including a link to this Answer in the Demonstration, you have my blessing to create and upload one yourself.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a version that uses only the Front End, which can be verified using LinkSnooper. This is mostly a useless optimisation/exploration.

```
width = 3;
height = 3;
n = width*height;
heldStates = 
  Join @@ (ToExpression["state" <> ToString[#], InputForm, Hold] & /@ 
     Range[n]);
groupedEdges =
  Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Table[Block[
     {sqs = {0}, index = xii + width (yjj - 1)}
     ,
     If[xii != width, AppendTo[sqs, 1]];
     If[xii != 1, AppendTo[sqs, -1]];
     If[yjj != height, AppendTo[sqs, width]];
     If[yjj != 1, AppendTo[sqs, -width]];
     index + # & /@ sqs]
    ,
    {yjj, 1, height},
    {xii, 1, width}
    ];
heldConnectedStates = heldStates[[#]] & /@ groupedEdges;
dynModVars =
  List @@@ 
   Hold@Evaluate[
     Set @@@ Thread[{heldStates, Hold @@ ConstantArray[False, n]}, 
       Hold]];
```

Heres the graphical stuff

```
interactiveRectangleMaker =
  Function[{sA, boxDirective, action},
   {DynamicBox[If[sA, RGBColor[1, 0, 1], RGBColor[0, 1, 0]]], 
    EventHandler[boxDirective, {"MouseDown" :> action}]}, HoldAll];
actionsHeld =
  Join @@ (CompoundExpression @@@ Hold[Evaluate[
         Join @@ 
          Function[Null, Hold[FEPrivate`Set[#, SameQ[#, False]]], 
            HoldAll] /@ #
         ]] & /@ heldConnectedStates);
doubleRange = Transpose@Outer[List, Range[width], Range[height]];
rectBoxes = Flatten@Map[RectangleBox, doubleRange, {2}];
argsHeld = 
  Thread[{heldStates, Hold @@ rectBoxes, actionsHeld }, Hold];
```

This makes the `DynamicModule`

```
DynamicModule @@
 {Unevaluated @@ dynModVars,
  Graphics[
   List @@ interactiveRectangleMaker @@@ argsHeld
   ,
   GridLines -> {Range[2, width], Range[2, height]}
   ]}
```