# How to deploy a simple game as an html page

Tags: html

I have taken the following code from the mister Wizard answer to my old question [Programming the fiver game](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120959/programming-the-fiver-game)

```
DynamicModule[{flip, v, c, square, gui},
 flip[i_, j_] :=
  (v[##] *= -1;) & @@@
   {{i, j}, {i + 1, j}, {i - 1, j}, {i, j + 1}, {i, j - 1}};

 _v = 1;
 {c[1], c[-1], c[0]} = {LightBlue, LightRed, Gray};

 square =
  Button[
    Spacer[{51, 51}], flip @ ##
    , Background -> Dynamic @ c @ v @ ##
    , Appearance -> None
  ] &;

 gui =
  Labeled[ #
    , {Button["Reset", ClearAll[v]; _v = 1],
        ColorSetter@*Dynamic@*c /@ {1, -1, 0} // Column}
    , {Bottom, Right}
  ] &;

 Grid[
     Array[square, {5, 5}]
     , Frame -> c[0]
     , Background -> c[0]
     , Spacings -> {{5, {1}, 5}, {5, {1}, 5}}/10
 ] // gui // Deploy
]
```

I would like to know if, as there is no call to external data, if it is possible do deploy it as an html page and hoçw to do this ? I have tried the suggested solutions in MSE but nothing works.

Comment: It's unlikely to be simple. There's no good Mathematica to JS converter that I know of and the Wolfram Cloud is an expensive minimally functional boondoggle.

Comment: @b3m2a1 A complete and utter boondoggle!!

Comment: M.R. could you say this again in a transparent language ?

Comment: M.R. means that it is useless