# Is there some way to make Dynamic track only a part of a variable

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I often run into a situation like the one exemplified by the code below. The basic idea is to use a single `DynamicModule` variable as a list or association of values that can be manipulated by individual controls:

```
n = 5;
DynamicModule[{
  var = AssociationThread[Range[5], RandomInteger[10, n]]
  },
 Column @ Map[
    Row[{
      Slider[Dynamic[var[#]], {0, 10, 1}],
      Dynamic[Echo@var[#], TrackedSymbols :> {var} (* var[#] cannot be used here *)]
      },
      "  "
    ]&,
    Keys[var]
  ]
]
```

In this example, whenever one slider is moved, all the `Dynamic`s fire (as you can tell from the `Echo`s) and that is not what I want. I'd like each `Dynamic` to listen only to changes in `var[i]`; not to the whole association `var`.

Of course, I could just localize `{var1, var2, var3, ...}` instead, but for arbitrary `n` this gets annoying and difficult to maintain.

I could also wrap each `Row` in its own `DynamicModule` that keeps a local copy of `var[i]` to be used for display purposes only and then modify the `Slider` to control both `var[i]` and its copy, but then it becomes quite difficult to make sure the displayed `Dynamic`s behave well when `var` changes externally (for example, if I want to have a reset button that sets all `var[i]` to zero).

I'm sure it's technically possible with some sort of meta-programming technique, but is there a more canonical way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate question: [64312](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64312/5478) and a topic with attempts to solve it: [174792](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174792/5478)