# ControlActive doesn't distinguish the active element in list-based controls

Tags: dynamic

There are three controls in the following code: the first one is a "stand-alone" one and the other two are based on the list `angle`. When one of the "angles" becomes active, all of them do the same. How to prevent it?

```
DynamicModule[{angle = Array[0 &, 2]},
 Panel@Dynamic@
   Column[{Row@{
      Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 2 Pi}], Dynamic[{x, ControlActive["a", "Inactive"]}]}, 
   Grid[
    MapIndexed[
       With[{i = #2[[1]]}, {Slider[Dynamic[angle[[i]]], {0, 2 Pi}], 
          Dynamic[{angle[[i]], ControlActive["Active", "Inactive"]}]}] &, angle]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: closely related: [How to track Part of Symbol \[...\]](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64312/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Ugh. `Dynamic` is a wild beast :(

Comment: "Dynamic is a wild beast" -- Yes, perhaps it is the proverbial dancing bear, of which was said: we should be grateful that it dances at all and not expect it to dance gracefully.

Answer (score 5):

It looks that `ControlActive` treats `angle` as a one variable which will be same for both `ControlActive`.

See if this help:

```
 DynamicModule[{angle = Array[0 &, 2]}, 
 Panel@Dynamic@
   Column[{Row@{Slider[Dynamic[x], {0, 2 Pi}], 
       Dynamic[{x, ControlActive["a", "Inactive"]}]}, 
     Grid[MapIndexed[
       With[{i = #2[[1]]}, {DynamicModule[{y}, 
           Row@{Slider[Dynamic[y, (angle[[i]] = y = #) &], {0, 2 Pi}],
              Dynamic[{y, ControlActive["Active", "Inactive"]}]}]}] &,
        angle]]}]]
```

Comment: Yep! It works :) I don't find the idea of nesting neat but .... :).Thans!

Comment: @Dr. belisarius I am trying to create different variable for each controller. The only way I have (for automatic goal) is to use DynamicModule. It is something like this `angle={a,b}` and then work with `a` and `b` instead of working with `angle` itself.

Comment: In my real problem I don't know a priori how many "angles" I will have

Comment: That is why is use `DynamicModule` to generate different variable for each element of `angle`

Comment: yes,yes. Your answer works.I was referring to your previous comment _"I am trying to create different variable"_

Comment: @Dr.belisarius and Algohli, worth to mention that those controllers are now only one way bouded with `angle`. If the stand-alone one uses `Dynamic[angle[[1]]]` it won'y be reflected by those grom grid.

Comment: won'y->won't  grom->from

Comment: @Kuba I want a sip of what you're drinking